# Targeting specific errors in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

We all run into errors using Drupal-- most of which are easy to fix. Some, however, are not so easy to fix and require many hours of digging even though the website works fine with the error.

My question: To work around this digging, is it possible to have Drupal assign a specific CSS class to each error so you can easily make it display:none?

If there isn't a way to do this, is it possible to assign a display:none; to the parent element (the error "div" in this case below) if - for example - the error string = `"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in element_children() (line 6282 of /var/www/html/includes/common.inc)."` using jQuery / Javascript?

```
<div class="messages error">
    <h2 class="element-invisible">Error message</h2>
    <em class="placeholder">Warning</em>
    : Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
    <em class="placeholder">element_children()</em>
    (line
    <em class="placeholder">6282</em>
    of
    <em class="placeholder">/var/www/html/includes/common.inc</em>
    ).
</div>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hiding error messages using CSS is a very very very bad idea. Instead, you should turn off error reporting to screen by going to **Administration » Configuration » Development » Logging and errors** and turning **Error messages to display** to **none**.

With that switched off, no one will see those errors but, as the admin, you can view them yourself by going to **Administration » Reports » Recent log messages**.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to alter how those messages are rendered, you need to override the `theme_status_messages()` theme function, which contains the following code.

```
function theme_status_messages($variables) {
  $display = $variables['display'];
  $output = '';

  $status_heading = array(
    'status' => t('Status message'), 
    'error' => t('Error message'), 
    'warning' => t('Warning message'),
  );
  foreach (drupal_get_messages($display) as $type => $messages) {
    $output .= "<div class=\"messages $type\">\n";
    if (!empty($status_heading[$type])) {
      $output .= '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . $status_heading[$type] . "</h2>\n";
    }
    if (count($messages) > 1) {
      $output .= " <ul>\n";
      foreach ($messages as $message) {
        $output .= '  <li>' . $message . "</li>\n";
      }
      $output .= " </ul>\n";
    }
    else {
      $output .= $messages[0];
    }
    $output .= "</div>\n";
  }
  return $output;
}
```

Rather than hiding messages with CSS styles, I would rather remove the messages from the list of messages to show, if you need to filter out specific messages.